# Wordpress Multisite keeps redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: multisite, migration, ssl, https

I would like to create a local development environment from my production, multisite, WordPress website. I have used the Migrate DB plugin with the following search and replace settings:

```
//domain.com  -> //domain.local

https://domain.com -> http://domain.local

https://domain.local -> http://domain.local

/data/sites/web/domain.com -> /var/www/html
```

Now it works all fine, locally, but **without** multisite enabled. As soon as Multisite is enabled it still tries to redirect me to HTTPS.

So as soon as I enable these settings in wp_config.php, I am not able to login at `http://domain.local/wp-admin` anymore:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain.local');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

And it redirects me from `http://domain.local/wp-admin` to `https://domain.local/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.local%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1` which causes an ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Any ideas what this is causing? Further I tried:

- empty all `active_plugins` cells in every `wp_options` table (so also for every subsite), so there should not be any active.
- Add `define('WP_CACHE', false);` at the top of wp_config.php

Not sure if there could be any other setting specifically for https in Multisites. As I just told, without multisite enabled in `wp-config.php` I am able to reach http://domain.local/wp-admin, but with multisite enabled I am not and it's trying to redirect me to an https domain which results in an error.

**EDIT:**

I seem to have found the issue, I have moved all plugins to a separate folder (temporarily) and now the website works. I am able to reach wp-admin without any issues. So a plugin still seem to be the problem, even though I have disabled all plugins via the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why my website was still redirecting to HTTPS was because of a plugin. The plugin was disabled, by emptying the database cell which contains the "active plugins", but still it was overruling every WordPress setting so it seemed. Every setting in `wp-config.php` which should overrule database settings or disabling/removing cache, didn't worked out. I tried literally everything which can be found on most blogs, the WordPress documentation etc.

But moving all plugins from `wp-content/plugins` to a temporary folder called `wp-content/plugins-backup` helped me to reach the admin page and by moving the plugins back to the `wp-content/plugins` folder, one by one (or a few at a time), helped me figuring out which plugin was the problem.